# Infinite loop when dispatching action that performs an AJAX request - ReactJS, Redux, Redux-saga

Tags: ajax, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I am trying to load data for a component using redux-saga and axios but I keep getting an infinite loop. These are the relevant components:

**App.js**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <header>
          <div className="pure-u-1 pure-u-sm-1-3">

          </div>
          <nav className="pure-u-1 pure-u-sm-2-3">
            <ul>
              <li><Link to="/meal-plans">Meal Plans</Link></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </header>
        <main>
          <div className="view-area">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={() => <DashBoard {...this.props} />} />
              <Route exact path="/meal-plans" component={() => <MealPlansContainer {...this.props} />} />
              <Route path="/meal-plans/:id" component={props => <MealPlan {...this.props} {...props} />} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    app: state.app,
    mealPlan: state.mealPlan,
    mealPlans: state.mealPlans,
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch);
}

App = withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App));

export default App;
```

**MealPlan.js**

```
class MealPlan extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        let id = this.props.match.params.id
        this.props.fetchMealPlan(id);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="meal-plan pure-g box">
                <div className="pure-u-1">
                    <p>Future Meal Plan Page</p>
                    <LoadingSpinner show={true} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I'm new to React and I don't have a good grasp on the component lifecycle, but I believe that componentDidMount() is being called each time the AJAX request completes and the 'FETCH_MEAL_PLAN_SUCCESSFUL' case runs in the reducer.

**actionCreators.js**

```
export function fetchMealPlan(id) {
  return {
    type: 'FETCH_MEAL_PLAN',
    id
  }
}

export function fetchMealPlanSuccessful(data) {
  return {
    type: 'FETCH_MEAL_PLAN_SUCCESSFUL',
    data
  }
}

export function fetchMealPlanFail(message) {
  return {
    type: 'FETCH_MEAL_PLAN_FAIL',
    message
  }
}
```

**sagas.js**

```
function* fetchMealPlan(action) {
  try {
    const mealPlan = yield call(api.get, '/meal_plans/' + action.id);
    yield put(fetchMealPlanSuccessful(mealPlan.data));
  } catch (e) {
    yield put(fetchMealPlanFail(e.message));
  }
}

function* watchFetchMealPlan() {
  yield takeLatest('FETCH_MEAL_PLAN', fetchMealPlan);
}
```

**mealPlan.js (reducer)**

```
function mealPlan(state = {}, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_MEAL_PLAN':
      return state;
    case 'FETCH_MEAL_PLAN_FAIL':
      return state;
    case 'FETCH_MEAL_PLAN_SUCCESSFUL':
      state = Object.assign({}, action.data);
      return state;
      break;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default mealPlan;
```

If I don't stop the app, it'll keep making requests. In this test, it made 4,200+ requests:
[App in an infinite loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2I4F.png)

I've spent hours researching how to best load data from my API for components after changing a route and so far I've been unsuccessful. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally a component should run `componentDidMount` once, unless it is deallocated and then mounted again. If its props or state change, then `componentDidUpdate` will be fired.

So if you are experiencing multiple `componentDidMount`, then it is likely that this component is nested as a child (I guess you did from your code snippet), and then when its parent's (App) state or props change, which will re-render its children (including MealPlan). Because you are connecting `mealPlan` & `mealPlan` from redux to App. Whenever you call the API, App's props will be updated, thus causing its children to be re-rendered, and causing MealPlan trigger `componentDidMount` again and again.

I am not super experience with React. But I have not seen the way you set up routes. One way is you define a router in separate file, and use the router like this (this is **not** using the code-splitting feature of react-router):

```
const router = (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
     <Route path="/meal-plans" component={MealPlan} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
)

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}> // react-redux provider
      { router }
    </Provider>,
  document.querySelector('#main'));
```

If you wanna do code-splitting, since you are using redux-sagas, a good template is https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate. By looking at the ways how they do it, you could achieve what you want

Comment: Thank you for you detailed answer. I believe you are correct about the problem being that I connected redux to my main app component. I haven't been making good use of container components to load data. I found these resources useful in understanding how to structure my app: [Connecting containers](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-generating-containers-with-connect-from-react-redux-visibletodolist) and [React + Redux container pattern](http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/the-react-plus-redux-container-pattern/).

Comment: Connecting my `MealPlan` component to redux instead of `App` solved my problem. I spent so many hours researching and struggling, I appreciate your help!